# PyVisa - Cannot connect via VICP but TCPIP works?

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am having an issue connect to a LeCroy oscilloscope using PyVisa v1.9.

If I trying to connect using the code:

```
import visa
from pyvisa.resources import MessageBasedResource

visa.log_to_screen()
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
my_instrument = rm.open_resource('VICP::10.2.72.141:INSTR', resource_pyclass=MessageBasedResource)
```

I get the error:  VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.

However, if I change to:

```
my_instrument = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::10.2.72.141:INSTR', resource_pyclass=MessageBasedResource)
```

The code with connect with the instrument, but the functions in my driver no longer work.  Read commands also respond with:

‘WARNING : CURRENT REMOTE CONTROL INTERFACE IS TCPIP’

I never saw an issue before moving to version 1.9 of pyvisa.

Python version is 2.7 64-bit, running on windows 10 64bit

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I've fixed it.....new computer os install, and I forgot the VICP passport install was missing.